# How do I redirect a paste to a file?

Tags: bash

I've copied a large e-mail (raw text) from one web terminal. I can paste that into the terminal, but I want to feed it to `sa-learn`. I was thinking one thing I could do here is use heredoc's. This syntax appears to work.

```
$ echo <<EOF | sa-learn --spam
<paste email>
EOF
```

However, it doesn't seem to work...

```
$ echo <<EOF > foo
AOSJFDOASDFJKOK
EOF

$ cat foo
(nothing)
```

How does a heredoc work in bash?

Comment: Interestingly enough `cat > foo <<EOF` would work, and `sa-learn --spam <<EOF`... what does the syntax that I've given do though, and why does it fail silently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` prints its arguments and ignores `stdin`. `<<EOF ... EOF` (a *here document* / *heredoc*) writes to `stdin`. As you noticed, `cat` reads from `stdin` (and writes it out), so it does read the heredoc. As `sa-learn` reads from `stdin`, it also reads the `heredoc`.

Comment: That makes sense.. `<<EOF ... EOF` is putting the input in STDIN not a file ... wonder why I why was thinking it was dropping it @ARGS....

Answer (score 4):

For anyone reading this question who happens to use Mac OS X, look at `pbpaste(1)`. It takes whatever's on your clipboard (NeXTStep used to call this the pasteboard, and the Cocoa APIs still do, hence the "pb") and outputs it to `stdout`.  So on a Mac you could do this with:

```
pbpaste | sa-learn --spam
```

Note also the related `pbcopy(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> would help here.

It allows you to quickly open an editor to write a long command. There also seem to be [alternatives](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1446/rapidly-invoke-an-editor-to-write-a-long-complex-or-tricky-command).